# What is the fastest way to write sequential data to disk under Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, macos, io

I need a way to store large data chunks(~1-2MB) at a high rate (~200-300Mbit/s).
After some research I found several options:

- `aio_write`
- Direct_IO
- Carbon File Manager's `PBWriteForkAsync()`
- default `fwrite()`, wrapped in a block and dispatched via GCD
- NSData's `appendData` in an NSOperation
- ...

This [wiki page](http://wiki.cs.pdx.edu/usb/asyncdebate.html) describes the state of `aio_write` under Linux. What I didn't find was a similar page about the state of `aio_write` for Mac OS X.

NSOperation or Blocks+GCD seems to be a technique to achieve non-blocking IO. It is used in several open source IO libraries (e.g. https://github.com/mikeash/MAAsyncIO)

Has someone with a similar problem found a suitable solution?
Currently I tend towards `PBWriteForkAsync` as it takes some 'tuning'parameters. It also should be 64-bit safe.

Comment: There's no way to tell short of benchmarks.  You might also consider mmap().

Comment: I will definitely measure. I am currently searching for all available options.

Comment: under osx aio_write is not a very good option as there is no way to get notified other than by signal. and even then, you don't get associated user data because that's not supported in osx. i would suggest to scrap aio_write from the list.

Comment: Thank you - Good to know! That probably saved me several hours :)

Comment: i already spent several days doing just that.. it works great on linux because you can attach user data (pointer to the aio struct which happened to finish writing) and get that as the data attached to a signal. it works even better in freebsd because you can use aio together with kevent/kqueue there which definitely gives you more speed and control. under osx, however, the only option with aio is receiving the signal and doing a loop over all your handles trying to see which handle actually finished its job :-/ that sucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know MacOS very well, but I'd also try `open` and `write` syscalls from `unistd.h` with the non-blocking option `O_NONBLOCK`. [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/open.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/open)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know O_NONBLOCK. I was aware of O_DIRECT (which is not available under OS X). Currently I use a custom approach that uses mmap & Grand Central Dispatch and it looks good so far. By using GCD my IO is also non-blocking and mmap is forcing me to do fast, page aligned writes.

Answer (score 1):

You should use unbuffered I/O for the writes, in Carbon this is `FSWriteFork()` with `kFSNoCacheBit`, in BSD use `fcntl()` with `F_NOCACHE`.

Rather than use the system's non-blocking IO, you may want to consider a worker thread to write the blocks sequentially using a queue. This will give you more control and may end up being simpler, particularly if you want to monitor the queue to see if you are keeping up or not.

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/FileSystem/Articles/FilePerformance.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I already experimented with PBWriteForkAsync as mentioned in the Apple doc you linked. Surprisingly that was slower than FSWriteFork. Eventually I ended up using 2 sequential mmap-ped regions. I write to one region until it is full. Then I switch, expand & re-mmap the file on a GCD background thread (protected with a semaphore).